# Unusual behavior of Reducer of map-reduce in Hadoop?

Tags: java, design-patterns, hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently working in pseudo-distributed mode in Hadoop. The way my reduce function works is: For each key it will create a arraylist of its value and then will make an instance of a singleton class [ This class is present in a library so I cannot change it ]. It then call a method of this instance.

Now my problem is: Suppose the map function emits 2 keys, then the reducer will only process one key for the another one it will say that "Java.lang.exception" the class[ the singleton one] cannot be instantiated.

My concern is why this is happening? As in pseudo-distributed mode each reducer run a different JVM!

Comment: Can it be possible that only 1 reducer is working and it gets to reduce both the keys? If yes, can you suggest any way to solve this?

Comment: Can you update your question with the reducer code you are using? Somebody might surely help you. :)

Comment: Check if you value of property mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks if you are running MRv2 or mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks for MRv1. Above property allow to utilize same JVM for multiple MapReduce task per jvm.