# Cannot instantiate single ton class in reducer in mapreduce hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, mapr

I call a method of singleton class in reducer. So I create a instance of the class. Tt works for one key and for the rest of the keys it says that it cannot instantiate the class[ "java.lang.exceptio"].

Comment: if You  give stacktrace then somebody might be able to help

Comment: Please elaborate a little more, if you can. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Udad, Is this question of yours closely related to this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756491/unusual-behavior-of-reducer-of-map-reduce-in-hadoop - It seems similar to my eye - sorry if it's not and you can always edit your question if want, if you want to update. :)